# Jquery animate() and google chrome issues

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

i'm having a problem with jquery and animate() in google Chrome.
I have a box which is initially hidden and positioned on the right outside the screen. 
When a box is clicked the hidden box becomes visible and animate from right to the center, it stops and blink, then and then it starts moving again to the left side of the screen and disapper. 
This thing works on Explorer and Firefox but not on Chrome.

This is the link:
http://test.gianlucaugolini.it/4545.html

And this is the code:

```
function test(){

    var scaleX = $("#container").width()/2 + $("#hoverText").width()/2;

    $("#hoverText").animate({visibility:"visible",opacity:"show",left:"-="+scaleX+"px"},500,function(){

    $("#hoverText").effect("highlight",{duration:1000},1500,function(){

    $("#hoverText").animate({visibility:"hidden",opacity:"hide",left:"0%"},500,function(){
        $("#hoverText").css("left","100%");

    });
        });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `100%` style `left` CSS properties vs the `px` properties in use here (with `-=` and `100%`, chrome is interpreting it as `0` pixels absent a valid value...meaning that it's working, but way off to the left of the visible area).

To eliminate the issue cross-browser, I recommend sticking with one or the other...and since you want to animate in a `-=` style, I'd say pixels is the way to go here.

Here's your example changed so that it that sets the `left` based on the container width:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header_title").bind("click",test);
});

function test(){
    var cw = $("#container").width();
    var scaleX = cw/2 + $("#hoverText").width()/2;  

    $("#hoverText").css("left", cw).animate({
        visibility: "visible",
        opacity: "show",
        left: "-="+scaleX+"px"
    }, 500, function() {
        $(this).effect("highlight",{
            duration:1000
        }, 1500, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                visibility: "hidden",
                opacity: "hide",
                left: 0
            });
        });
    });
}
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vEha2/), this version will work cross-browser.

Comment: I just had the same issue where my initial css specified "bottom:0px" but i was using jquery to animate as follows "top:+=2500". Changing the js to read "bottom:-=2500" made it consistent and now it works in Chrome/IE.

Comment: instead of top, use `{"padding-top":"+=15px"}` to be relative