# Jquery issue in IE, Chrome but not in FF

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Having some problems with a piece of Jquery code, well that's where I think the problem is - On FF when the page loads after 2 seconds it animates panels from the left of the screen to the right. It looks fine without any issues but in Chrome and IE it jumps back and continues moving across.

Here is the code -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(function() {

   // Display div slowly
    $('#one').delay(2000).show('slow');
    $("#one").animate({
        left: '+=159'
    }, 3000);


    $('#two').delay(3000).show('slow');
    $("#two").animate({
        left: '+=159'
    }, 3000);

    $('#three').delay(4000).show('slow');
    $("#three").animate({
        left: '+=159'
    }, 3000);

    $('#four').delay(5000).show('slow');
    $("#four").animate({
        left: '+=159'
    }, 3000);
    });

 </script>
```

Here is a preview of the page - http://www.visrez.com/preview/och-group/

P.S I'm not ruling out it's a css issue...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gearóid

Comment: the script example shows that the OP is using a document ready structure, only the shorthand `$(function(){});` so this is not the problem

Comment: @Gearóid: It's the browser problem and you need to change the script, i guess. Please check this thread; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455831/jquery-animate-and-google-chrome-issues

Comment: @sander, @ Karthik rangaraj Thanks for the suggestions. I've fixed it to a point by changing around the layout. now it's fine in ie8, chrome and FF but ie7 isn't playing nice. I'll see if I can fix it myself, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that Chrome isn't taking into account the position (relative to the offset parent) that `div` has on the page before you start moving it. So, once animated, it has a value of `left: 159px` which is relative to the body. Firefox is taking the original position into account and ends with `left: 256px`.

I haven't looked into *why* this happens yet but here are a few things that you could do (workarounds):

1. Before animating figure out the position relative to the offset parent and set the CSS `top` and `left` attributes. Then, hopefully, the final value will be the value that you set plus 159px. Something like:

   ```
   var offset = $("#one").offset();
   $("#one").css({"top": offset.top, "left": offset.left});
   // animate
   ```
2. Wrap `#oneTop` and `#one` and each other pair in a div that is `position: relative`. This will set the offset parent of the animated div to the `position: relative` div. This way the +159px is relative to where the div would be in the document.

Answer (score 0):

i prepared a demo with your code
and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/AjDLS/2/

i don't have your problem, so that makes me think you must have some other javascript issue, or css issue, could you post more code?

Comment: Thanks for the help Sander, I'm going to take a different approach to it.